# Not able to edit web.config in InetPub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I published my MVC 5 application under IIS\Default Web Site.

I want to edit web.config file. When I go to the Inetpub\wwwroot folder and try to edit and save, it shows Access Denied.

How can I edit it?

Comment: You should edit it as administrator. Open Notepad++ or Notepad as administrator, then open file within editor. Or another workaround, copy it to desktop, edit, and then copy back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start `Notepad` (or whatever you are using) AS `administrator` by right clicking the `notepad.exe` and choosing `run as administrator` then you can edit and save the file

> c:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe > Run as Administrator > Edit > Save